# Return array of SQL results in php to be converted to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, return

I am trying to take a number of user entries from a SQL database and return it where it will be encoded to JSON and sent back to android.

Currently I am building the part to handle the results from querying the database:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE tower='$tower'") or die(mysql_error());
    $resultNo = mysql_num_rows($result);

    // check for successful store
    if ($result != null) {

        //if just one result return it
        if ($resultNo == 1) {
            // return result
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);

    //if more than one loop through
    } else {

        //add each row to an array
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $resultSet[] = $row;
        }
        return $resultSet[];

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code I am returning to is...

```
$result = $db->searchForPeople($tower);
```

Can I return either an array or a single result in this way or should I just add the single result to the array and return that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure you pasted your code correctly? The inner `} else {` doesn't have a closing `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can this way:

```
$resultSet['row'] = $row;
return json_encode($resultSet);
```

or for example:

```
function TEST()
{
$array=array();$i=0;       
while($result=mysql_fetch_row(QUERY))       
{
    foreach ($result as $key=>$value){
       if(!isset($array[$i])) $array[$i] = array();
        $array[$i][$key] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}     
return $array;
}
```